# Sum arrays from TreeMap

Tags: java, arrays, treemap

I have multiple arrays stored in a TreeMap, then I want to retrieve these arrays and multiply them by a number. The after that I want to sum each column values in a new array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class readingLargeFile {
    static String[] words;
    static  Map<String, double[]> m1 = new TreeMap();
    static Map<String,Double> m2 = new TreeMap();
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //First TreeMap
         double count[]={3.9, 1.2, 6.2, 1.8, 7.6, 3.8};
         double count1[]={1.6, 7.2, 6.2, 2.3, 1.8, 0.0};
         double count2[]={1.6, 5.5, 1.8, 8.8, 0.0, 0.0};
         double count3[]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.3, 0.0, 0.0};
         double count4[]={2.0, 2.2, 1.2, 3.9, 2.3, 4.4};
         double count5[]={3.4, 0.0, 1.9, 2.4, 0.5, 2.0};
            m1.put("apple",count);
            m1.put("orange",count1);
            m1.put("banana",count2);
            m1.put("cherry",count3);
            m1.put("lemon",count4);
            m1.put("strawbarry",count5);

        //for(Map.Entry<String, double []> e : m1.entrySet()) {//print First TreeMap content

        //System.out.println(e.getKey()+":"+Arrays.toString(e.getValue()));
            //}

               //second TreeMap
        m2.put("apple", 2.1);
        m2.put("cherry", 1.9);
        m2.put("grasb", 3.0);
        m2.put("strawbarry", 4.1);

        double[] finalSum = new double[6];
        double first=0;
        double second=0;
        double third=0;
        double fourth=0;
        double fifth=0;
        double sixth=0;

        String key="";
                 for ( Map.Entry<String,Double> entry : m2.entrySet() ) {//for loop through the second TreeMap
                      if ( m1.containsKey(entry.getKey()) ) {//check if the first TreeMapp contain same key from second TreeMap
                          //if the key is common in m1 and m2, multiply the values

                          key=entry.getKey();
                       double y=entry.getValue();//the number from second TreeMap 
                       double w[]=m1.get(entry.getKey());//the array from first TreeMap
                       //for loop to multiple the array from first TreeMap by the number in second TreeMap for same key
                       /*for example if the key=apple
                         then
                         {3.9*2.1, 1.2*2.1, 6.2*2.1, 1.8*2.1, 7.6*2.1, 3.8*2.1}
                         */ 
                       for (int u=0;u<w.length;u++){
                           finalSum[u]=  w[u]*y;}
                       System.out.println(key+"     "+Arrays.toString(finalSum));
                       }}


                 for (int u=0,t=0;u<finalSum.length;u++,t++){
                   first+=finalSum[t];
                   second+=finalSum[t];
                   third+=finalSum[t];
                   fourth+=finalSum[t];
                   fifth+=finalSum[t];
                   sixth+=finalSum[t];
                 }
                   System.out.println(first+"\n"+second+"\n"+third+"\n"+fourth+"\n"+fifth+"\n"+sixth);}}
```

Then this my output:

```
apple     [8.19, 2.52, 13.020000000000001, 3.7800000000000002, 15.959999999999999, 7.9799999999999995]
cherry     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.369999999999999, 0.0, 0.0]
strawbarry     [13.939999999999998, 0.0, 7.789999999999999, 9.839999999999998, 2.05, 8.2]
41.81999999999999
41.81999999999999
41.81999999999999
41.81999999999999
41.81999999999999
41.81999999999999
```

Anyone know what's the problem.:(

Comment: can you post your full code, so nothing is left out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINAL EDIT**
*After the reconstructed question, i have made changes to formerly proposed solutions, though still using the same aproach, see below at "original answer" for details*

Here is the final fixed code for the issue, adressing the issues as formerly stated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ReadingLargeFile {
    static String[] words;
    static Map<String, double[]> m1 = new TreeMap();
    static Map<String, Double> m2 = new TreeMap();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //First TreeMap
        double count[] = {3.9, 1.2, 6.2, 1.8, 7.6, 3.8};
        double count1[] = {1.6, 7.2, 6.2, 2.3, 1.8, 0.0};
        double count2[] = {1.6, 5.5, 1.8, 8.8, 0.0, 0.0};
        double count3[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.3, 0.0, 0.0};
        double count4[] = {2.0, 2.2, 1.2, 3.9, 2.3, 4.4};
        double count5[] = {3.4, 0.0, 1.9, 2.4, 0.5, 2.0};
        m1.put("apple", count);
        m1.put("orange", count1);
        m1.put("banana", count2);
        m1.put("cherry", count3);
        m1.put("lemon", count4);
        m1.put("strawbarry", count5);

        //second TreeMap
        m2.put("apple", 2.1);
        m2.put("cherry", 1.9);
        m2.put("grasb", 3.0);
        m2.put("strawbarry", 4.1);

        double[][] addedresults = getFinalSums(m1, m2);
        double[] finalResults = getSummedColumns(addedresults);

        System.out.println("added value arrays: " + Arrays.deepToString(addedresults));
        System.out.print("final summed array: " + Arrays.toString(finalResults));

    }

    public static double[] getSummedColumns(double[][] array) {
        double[] results = new double[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                results[i] += array[j][i];
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static double[][] getFinalSums(Map<String, double[]> m1, Map<String, Double> m2) {

        int sharedSums = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : m2.entrySet())
            if (m1.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
                sharedSums++;

        double[][] finalSum = new double[sharedSums][];

        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : m2.entrySet()) {//for loop through the second TreeMap
            if (m1.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {//check if the first TreeMapp contain same key from second TreeMap
                //if the key is common in m1 and m2, multiply the values

                double y = entry.getValue();//the number from second TreeMap
                double w[] = m1.get(entry.getKey());//the array from first TreeMap

                finalSum[i] = new double[w.length]; // instantiate the new array in the 2d array

                for (int j = 0; j < w.length; j++) {
                    finalSum[i][j] = w[j] * y; // add in the values in the correct spot in the 2d array
                }
                i++; // increase the current spot in the 2d array
            }
        }
        return finalSum;
    }
}
```

Here is the output produced by this class

> added value arrays: [[8.19, 2.52, 13.020000000000001, 3.7800000000000002, 15.959999999999999, 7.9799999999999995], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.369999999999999, 0.0, 0.0], [13.939999999999998, 0.0, 7.789999999999999, 9.839999999999998, 2.05, 8.2]]
>
> final summed array: [22.129999999999995, 2.52, 20.810000000000002]

**EDIT Original Answer**

```
for (int u=0;u<w.length;u++){
    finalSum[u]=  w[u]*number;//multibly the array with the number                              
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalSum));}//print the array
}
```

Notice how that you are writing out the result every time, but then at the next run of the loop, you are overwriting the result, this is where you need the 2d array as in

```
double[][] finalSum = new int[w.length][];

for(int i = 0; i < w.length; i++){
    for (int u=0;u<w.length;u++){
            finalSum[i][u]=  w[u]*number;//multibly the array with the number                              
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalSum));}//print the array
    }
}
```

now every row of the array should be saved, in the 2d array, and then it can be accesed and summed as described below

**EDITED** *now adding columns as requested, still assuming it as a 2d array structure*

*The issue you are facing as i see it is the way you are summing the data up.*

Made a small example to show how to sum up the column values in a 2d array

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        NewClass newClass = new NewClass();
        newClass.method();
    }

    public void method(){
        int[][] array = new int[6][6];
        int[] results = new int[6];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(i <= array.length/2)
                array[i][j] = j * i;
            else
                array[i][j] = j+i;
            }
        for(int i =0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
            {
                results[i] += array[j][i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Array" + Arrays.deepToString(array));
        System.out.println("results: " + Arrays.toString(results));
    }
}
```

This produces an output like this

> Array[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
>
> results: [9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49]

Note that a TreeMap is also a set of 2 list when the value contains a list/array so a similar aproach based on the rest of your code is apliable

Comment: @Greek assuming this is what you need ?

Comment: Hi Mikenno thanks for your answer, I try the first of by add the "t" inside the for loop, but the result still same, The summation is the last row of the array repeated six times. For the second solution, this is not like my case, my case is many double array stored in TreeMap, then I retrieve them and multiply then by a number after that sum the column of these arrays. I hope you got what I mean:)

Comment: @Geek reread the answer what you want is to add up colums ... well still same principle but target the columms instead, adjusted the code as to sum up the columms, still using a 2d array since the structure above is 6 sub arrays.

Comment: @Geek if this is still not it please provide a more specific definition of the data structure, such as Map <key,Double [][]> or how the structure may look

Comment: @Geek think i located the issue, it was somewhere else, though my other part of the solution still aplies

Comment: I add the code in the question, can you please see it. Thank you so much.

Comment: no not solved, the problem is in the first ,second...sixth, I want these values is the sum of all arrays columns. such as the first=22.1299 , second=2.52 ... and so on.

Comment: @Geek i'll try and look at it again then

Comment: @Geek alright got it working, fixing it up and then adding it to the answer, i did not make it crash proof, you'll have to make sure that you acces the right engths etc yourself

Comment: where is the answer you got? are you wrote it in your answer?

Comment: @Geek added it just now (was cleaning it up), if it works, pls remember to upvote and mark as answer :)

Comment: great it works well, but the result must be an array of size 6, because I want to sum all the columns. The answer must be [22.129999999999995, 2.52, 20.810000000000002,17.989,18.0099,16.1799]. I try to change the size from 3 to 6, but I got an exception.

Comment: @Geek this should probally fix it as well

Comment: I see the code, and I think how can I change the value "3", I don't want to add specific value, because I don't know how many match key between the two TreeMaps. But the problem is how can I know how many matching key before I enter the comparison"the checking of the keys between the maps".

Comment: I got it, in the method getSummedColumms. change the declaration of result array into.     double[] results = new double[m1.size()];
so that the size of the array will be same size of first map, then the summation will be done to all the values. I really thank you for your help.

Comment: @Geek no problem, hf with the programming :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should define int t=0; before for loop. not sure though

Comment: If you're not sure about your given answer, please use the comment section instead of posting an answer.

Comment: I wanted to. but i dont have enough rep yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can `iterate` through the `Map` and calculate sum using Java 8's `stream`, e.g.:

```
Map<String, double[]> data = new TreeMap<>(); // Map of double arrays
for(Map.Entry<String, double[]> entry : data.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(entry.getValue()).sum());

}
```

**Update**

If you want the `sum` of columns after multiplication, you can use the following:

```
Map<String, double[]> m1 = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String, Double> m2 = new TreeMap<>(); 

double count[] = { 3.9, 1.2, 6.2, 1.8, 7.6, 3.8 };
double count1[] = { 1.6, 7.2, 6.2, 2.3, 1.8, 0.0 };
double count2[] = { 1.6, 5.5, 1.8, 8.8, 0.0, 0.0 };
double count3[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.3, 0.0, 0.0 };
double count4[] = { 2.0, 2.2, 1.2, 3.9, 2.3, 4.4 };
double count5[] = { 3.4, 0.0, 1.9, 2.4, 0.5, 2.0 };
m1.put("apple", count);
m1.put("orange", count1);
m1.put("banana", count2);
m1.put("cherry", count3);
m1.put("lemon", count4);
m1.put("strawbarry", count5);

m2.put("apple", 2.1);
m2.put("cherry", 1.9);
m2.put("grasb", 3.0);
m2.put("strawbarry", 4.1);

for(Map.Entry<String, double[]> entry : m1.entrySet()){
    if(m2.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
        double multiplier = m2.get(entry.getKey());
        double[] values = entry.getValue();
        for(int i=0 ; i<values.length ; i++){
            values[i] = values[i] * multiplier;
        }
    }
}

//Multiplication done, now sum the columns
double sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<6 ; i++){
    for(Map.Entry<String, double[]> entry : m1.entrySet()){
        sum += entry.getValue()[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum = 0;
}
```

Comment: This way will sum each array independent "rows", for my case I wanna multiply each row of the array in the TreeMap by a number, then sum the columns. How can I do that?

Comment: You can just multiply the sum with any number in the `sysout` statement itself, e.g. `System.out.println(5 * Arrays.stream(entry.getValue()).sum());` Which number you want to multiply the sum with?

Comment: the method .sum(), it will sum each row independent right? not the columns? I add my code in the question above, can you look at it please. Thank you so much Darshan

Comment: hi Darshan, in the sum of the columns, you go through all the arrays in the TreeMap "m1", and this is I don't want, because I want to sum only the match key from two TreeMaps. I really love the sum of the columns you wrote because it simple. Can you see how can I sum only the columns of matching keys? I add it inside the multiplication loop , but it doesn't work as I want.